# Reflection error converting to Swift 4 in Objective-C properties

Tags: objective-c, swift, reflection

Getting error message

> Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<objc_property_t>?' (aka 'Optional<UnsafeMutablePointer>') to specified type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<objc_property_t?>' (aka 'UnsafeMutablePointer<Optional<OpaquePointer>>')

On this line

```
let properties : UnsafeMutablePointer <objc_property_t?> = class_copyPropertyList(self.classForCoder, &count)
```

Full code here

```
var count = UInt32()
let properties : UnsafeMutablePointer <objc_property_t?> = class_copyPropertyList(self.classForCoder, &count)
var propertyNames = [String]()
let intCount = Int(count)
for i in 0..<intCount {
    let property : objc_property_t = properties[i]!
    guard let propertyName = NSString(utf8String: property_getName(property)) as? String else {
        debugPrint("Couldn't unwrap property name for \(property)")
        break
    }

    propertyNames.append(propertyName)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`class_copyPropertyList()` returns a `UnsafeMutablePointer<objc_property_t>?` and not a `UnsafeMutablePointer<objc_property_t?>`.  It is usually better to avoid explicit type annotations and just write

```
let properties = class_copyPropertyList(self.classForCoder, &count)
```

and let the compiler infer the type. The optional must then be unwrapped, for example with `guard`:

```
guard let properties = class_copyPropertyList(self.classForCoder, &count) else {
    return // Handle error ...
}
```

The Swift `String` creation can also be simplified, leading to

```
var count = UInt32()
guard let properties = class_copyPropertyList(self.classForCoder, &count) else {
    return
}
var propertyNames = [String]()
for i in 0..<Int(count) {
    let propertyName = String(cString: property_getName(properties[i]))
    propertyNames.append(propertyName)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because the return type of `class_copyPropertyList` is not `UnsafeMutablePointer<objc_property_t?>`.

Your line should read

```
let properties : UnsafeMutablePointer <objc_property_t> = class_copyPropertyList(self.classForCoder, &count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove type annotation, like so:

```
var count = UInt32()
let properties = class_copyPropertyList(self.classForCoder, &count)
```

Now the properties can also be mapped:

```
if let properties = class_copyPropertyList(self.classForCoder, &count) {
    let range = 0..<Int(count)
    let names = range.map {
        String(cString: property_getName(properties[$0]))
    }
}
```